# what is "function()" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How does this code sample differ from a normal function declaration paired with an if statement for the event trigger? Is brevity the only advantage?

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Bakudan: It is not executed once. It is executed when the event is fired. Which is usually more than once, and the above code will (without errors) fire multiple times.

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying there. Anonymous functions can be called as many times as others, given the appropriate access. See my comment below, the second example. You may copy the last line as many times as you can. There is no immediate limit to the amount of times an anonymous function can be called.

Comment: @Bakudan: No, you mean self-exuting (mostly anonymus) function expressions. Every function you have a reference to can be executed multiple times.

Comment: You know, two and a half years later, being fully fluent in JS now and looking back at this, the 6 downvotes are total bullshit. Anonymous functions are not exactly self-explanatory, nor is there some easy way to look them up without knowing what they're called. The semi-functional nature of JS is definitely confusing at first to non-Lispers, and the hostile response I got to this question infuriates me. Have some f***ing sympathy for people who are learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript you may have what is called an anonymous function. In the above code, the anonymous function will be executed when the xmlhttp.onreadystatechange event is fired. Other examples are:

```
window.onkeypress = function(e) {
    alert(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
}
```

Or you could create an anonymous variable-function...

```
var myFunc = function(msg) {    // Create function and assign to var
    alert(msg);
}
myFunc("Hello World");          // Call new 'function'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding the question and giving a precise and correct answer. It's amazing to me how few managed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The identifier *function* is a reserved word that is the start of either a *FunctionDeclaration* or *FunctionExpression*. If it's at the start of a statement (or more correctly, in a place where a statement can be), it is interpreted as a *FunctionDeclaration* and must be of the form:

```
function <name> (<parameter list>) { <function body> }
```

the name in a *FunctionDeclaration* is required.

If it's not at the start of a statement, it is a *FunctionExpression* and the name is optional, e.g. it can be:

```
(function () {…})

var a = function () {…};

someFunction(function () {…})
```

and so on. In all cases, it returns a reference to the function that can be assigned (e.g. to a variable), called, passed to some other function, or ignored.

Comment: RobG, this is a very good answer however I think a bit wore thought could be put into simplifying it for the OP, and anyone else who should stumble upon this in the future. However votes up for an otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its represent the function that is going to be called for the given event occurs.

In you context when the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=` event occurs the `function()` block is get executed.

You can also write this as

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=myfunction;

function myfunction()
{
 //code to execute
}
```

Comment: This equivalence was something I was seeking to confirm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal function which is assigned to `onreadystatechange` property of `xmlhttp` object and can be triggered with:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange();
```

See the tutorial:

- [Functions: declarations and expressions](http://javascript.info/tutorial/functions-declarations-and-expressions)

to know more about it.

*You should really learn basics first :)*

Comment: so, when you call it , does it repeat all the work once again ?

Comment: @kommradHomer: Once a function is created, it can be called as many times as needed. After all, that's what functions are for.

Comment: what if it returns a value ? a value thats not bound to anything and will turn the same always ?

Comment: @Aerovistae `you cannot call the function from elsewhere in the code` Why? What makes you think so?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript supports the anonymous function object. 
When you want to execute a block of code related to an event, you must wrap your into a function. If you don't need a specific function for that (you don't want to reuse the code), you can leave your function anonymous.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { ... }
```

It is similar with doing this :

```
function foo() { ... }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = foo;
```

but in this case, you can reuse foo wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a function. Think of it as a block of code that can be executed at a later time.

Comment: You didn't think about this at all. See other responses for "tips on improvement."

Answer (score 0):

`function(){...}` is a nameless ("anonymous") [function expression](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/). If you assign it to a variable or use it as a argument, it does not need a name. In your example, you assign that function object to a handler property of the xhr object, where it will get used as a callback.